# Read Write files in different encoding formats

Tags: java, swing, file-io

I am writing a Java swing application which can store resumes (txt,pdf,docx,doc etc.) in a database (derby with Hibernate). The column which stores the resume is defined of type clob.

The resume file inputted by the user and the one fetched from the database do not match. I am assuming here that I am facing an encoding decoding issue here. Am I correct? Does anybody know a work around to this?

Comment: The skill lies in answering a question rather than finding problems with the question....JB Nizet's solution worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be an encoding issue when reading/writing the text to the file system. But I doubt you have a database problem, because the JDBC driver takes care of encoding/decoding based on the column definition.

You might have problems if you try to store "special" characters in a column which has an encoding which does not support these "special" characters. ASCII and ISO-8859-1 don't support the whole unicode character set, for example. UTF-8 supports everything.

What bothers me the most is that you're storing pdf, docx and doc files in a CLOB. Those file formats are binary formats, and not text formats. You should use a BLOB to store them.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, thanks for your response. Your solution was perfect and changing the type to BLOB did the trick. Thanks again!!!